# how I can create customs steps with DirectionsRoute in mapbox

Tags: java, android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm trying to create my custom Route with MapBox and add a list of customs steps. 
To draw a route from a list of Point, I'm using MapboxMapMatching. 
From MapBox documentation, I understand that steps are managed by **LegStep** but I can't houw I add my custom Steps if it is possible ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for "[Milestones](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/milestones/)", which are included in the Android Navigation SDK [out of the box](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/navigation-sdk/navigation/0.28.0/com/mapbox/services/android/navigation/v5/milestone/Milestone.html). Per the linked documentation, you can add custom milestones with an explicit method call:

```
navigation.addMilestone(new RouteMilestone.Builder()
      .setIdentifier("begin-route-milestone")
      .setTrigger(
        Trigger.all(
              Trigger.lt(TriggerProperty.STEP_INDEX, 3),   
              Trigger.gt(TriggerProperty.STEP_DISTANCE_TOTAL_METERS, 200)))
      .build()
```

Comment: Thanks riastrad!  Yeah we need a more clear definition of "custom steps" in this case.  What kind of custom behavior are you trying to achieve?